# How to render only audio from command line?

Tags: rendering, scripting, video-sequence-editor, command-line

Yes, how do we render ONLY audio from command line? I know there is an option to do it from the GUI, but I don't want that. Don't be too critical, as I'm still a newbie. Thanks.